# How to load/go to new page after bootstrap search submittion?

Tags: jquery, express, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a search input field such :

[image]

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

The current "search.html" webpage is .com/search/ and **I want to load/go to the webpage .com/cat.** Which way to go ?

https://jsfiddle.net/fvqrtzq3/

Answer (score 1):

Add an action to the form:

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="/cat">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `action="/cat"` attribute to your `form` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can call a JS function to get to job done

```
<button type="submit" onclick="redirect()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

function redirect(){
   window.location.assign(url);
   return true;
}
```

Note: If you return false, the form wont be submited =)